# JavaScript instead of jQuery form submit()

Tags: forms, submit

I am trying to convert a page from jQuery to pure JavaScript.

The "submit" is the issue.  I have tried everything I can think of.

I can not get the following line working when switched to JS:

I tried switching it to:

The code in context is below.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function excel( )
{
 $( '#dataToDisplay' ).val( $( '#jfabtable' ).html( ) );  // replacing with JavaScript
}
</script>

<!-- the following line works, but is jQuery -->
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='$("#savetoexcelform").submit();'><img src='./excel.png' width='48' height='48' border='0' title='Download to Excel' alt='Download to Excel' /></a>

<form action='convert.php' name='savetoexcelform' id='savetoexcelform' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit='return excel( );'>
 <input type='hidden' id='dataToDisplay' name='dataToDisplay'>
 <input type='hidden' id='filename' name='filename' value='output.xls'>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function excel( )
{
 document.getElementById( 'dataToDisplay' ).value = document.getElementById( 'jfabtable' ).innerHTML;  // replaced, tested and works
}
</script>

<!-- the following line is JS, but doesn't work -->
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='document.getElementById( "savetoexcelform" ).submit( );'><img src='./excel.png' width='48' height='48' border='0' title='Download to Excel' alt='Download to Excel' /></a>

<form action='convert.php' name='savetoexcelform' id='savetoexcelform' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit='return excel( );'>
 <input type='hidden' id='dataToDisplay' name='dataToDisplay'>
 <input type='hidden' id='filename' name='filename' value='output.xls'>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention javascript assume that the validation is already execute on submit the form by code. I suggest you change the logic to format the values before call form.submit.

The code below can help.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='submitForm()'>
<img src='./excel.png' width='48' height='48' border='0' title='Download to Excel' alt='Download to Excel' />
</a>

<form action='convert.php' name='savetoexcelform' id='savetoexcelform' method='post' target='_blank' onsubmit='return formatForm();'>
  <input type='hidden' id='dataToDisplay' name='dataToDisplay'>
  <input type='hidden' id='filename' name='filename' value='output.xls'>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitForm()
    {
        formatForm();
        document.getElementById( "savetoexcelform" ).submit( );
    }

    function formatForm()
    {
         document.getElementById( 'dataToDisplay' ).value = 
         document.getElementById( 'jfabtable' ).innerHTML;  // replaced, tested and works
}
</script>
```

Comment: That solved the issue.  Thank you very much for your post.  This was driving me nuts.